# simple sql join

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference between these statements? I've been using the first as a default, but it recently gave me an incorrect value that was solved by the second. Going from 1 to 2 has never changed a value for me when 1 returned the desired result.

```
1. JOIN table
   ON x = y and a = b

2. JOIN table
   ON (x = y and a = b)
```

Comment: in what situation did it return a different result? are you sure that's all you changed?

Comment: Can you show the actual query?

Comment: For all intents and purposes they are the same; and should return the same results.  Something else is happening.

Comment: Post both queries in their entirety.  This can't be the only change if the results are different.  *(Either the data changed underneath you, or some other part of the query changed.  Or perhaps you've simplified out something very relevant.)*

Comment: Evidently, I consistently made some other error all morning that I can no longer reproduce which was responsible for the different results. My only thought is that I was screwing up my JOINS with multiple tables and somehow statement 2 fixed my problem by greatly reducing the amount of rows in the query result. Would 1 and 2 remain the same for all JOIN types?

Comment: It will, because of operator precedence: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are required to be used when you have AND on OR conditions in your statement to avoid shortcircuits, just like this:

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE  col1 > 1 AND col2 < 3 AND col3 >= OR col3 = 1 AND col5 < 1
```

The above query will give you unexpected result as it will not determine the correct condition it will take. A round brackets will help you segregate condition in this case,

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE  col1 > 1 AND col2 < 3 AND (col3 >= OR col3 = 1) AND col5 < 1
```

hope it helps